# closure compiler / uglifyjs - this.function name not shortened?

Tags: jquery, function, compression, google-closure-compiler, uglifyjs

If I run this piece of code through closure compiler or uglifyjs, this.init is not shortened.. Can anyone tell me why that is?

```
function test() {
    var v = "abc";
    this.init = function() {
         alert('var = ' + v + ' and func = ' + f());
         f2();
    }
    function f() {
        return 'def';
    }
    function f2() {
        v = "ghi";
        alert('blabla');
        alert('filler');
    }
}

test();
```

uglifyjs turns this into :

```
function test(){function c(){a="ghi",alert("blabla"),alert("filler")}function b(){return"def"}var a="abc";this.init=function(){alert("var = "+a+" and func = "+b()),c()}}test()
```

Beautified that is:

```
function test() {
    function c() {
        a = "ghi", alert("blabla"), alert("filler")
    }
    function b() {
        return "def"
    }
    var a = "abc";
    this.init = function () {
        alert("var = " + a + " and func = " + b()), c()
    }
}

test()
```

So why is this.init() not changed as well to a shorter name?

Additionally, what exactly is the difference between doing:

```
 function init() {..}
```

and

```
 this.init = function() { .. }
```

Thanks,
Wesley

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`init` is not shortened for the same reason `test` is not shortened ... because it is part of the public API of your code.

When you call `var t = new test()` you would create an object that looks like this:

```
{
    init: function() { ... },
    prototype: test
}
```

and you can call `t.init()`.  If the compiler did not respect those variables which are available from the global scope, you would have to inline *all* of your JavaScript code into one file before you minified it.  Otherwise, every time you minified `test.js` the public function `test`'s name would change.  So this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var t = new test();
t.init();
</script>
```

would break (because `test` would **probably** be changed to `a` by the minifier and init to some other letter.)

As to the second part of your question, when you do `this.init = function` you are setting an attribute on an indeterminate object (it could be anything, since `this` is set at call time in JavaScript and you are declaring it inside of the function `test`).  When you write `function init(){}` you are writing a [function declaration](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/), which will be hoisted to the top of the enclosing scope (meaning you can call it, inside of the scope in which it is defined, before you have defined it.) However, it will not be available outside of `test`.

Comment: Public api? I'm not even calling it. This happens with any function that starts with "this." -- is this assumed to all be public methods?

Comment: @Wesley - It doesn't matter whether you're calling it or not in this particular instance. What matters is that the `init` function is a publicly accessible member of the `test` constructor function and therefore its name cannot be shortened/minified, otherwise a consumer of your code may try to call `new test().init()` and get `undefined` returned.

Comment: @Wesley, also Uglify has no way to tell whether you have another script included after this one which uses "init".

Comment: It would be shortened if you were to used Closure Compiler's ADVANCED mode which does global code removal, but it has strict rules about declaring externally names variables and properties.

Comment: It would be shortened by closure compiler if it finds that no one calls it unless you explicitly declared it as an extern